# docker local host:8888 not opening

Tags: docker

i have created a task-management-compose.yml in which I added

```
version: '3.1'

services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    restart: always
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: 123456
    ports:
      - 5432:5432

  adminer:
    image: adminer
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8888:8080

  # rabbitmq:
  #   image: rabbitmq:3-management
  #   ports:
  #     - "15672:15672"
  #     - "5672:5672"
```

after then I open command line and type `docker-compose -f task-management-compose.yml up -d` its work fine [image]

but when I type localhost:8888 it shows nothing
[image]

Comment: One possibility is that your local docker client controls a remote docker server.  I seem to recall that can be set up with `docker machine`.  In such a case, the port 8888 is on that remote machine.  Ideally you would know whether the docker engine is local or not. `docker info` can help identify the server (see Name field, O/S, etc.).

Comment: There must be something wrong with your config. Try to remove `-d` daemon option from your docker-compose command so any errors will be displayed directly on the cli. Any error message will give us some clue.

Comment: ERROR: error pulling image configuration: Get https://production.cloudflare.docker.com/registry-v2/docker/registry/v2/blobs/sha256/7e/7e4d58f0e5f3b60077e9a5d96b4be1b974b5a484f54f9393000a99f3b6816e3d/data?verify=1601297513-TGKztz4U0Ws7vuXEIocosFJRkUA%3D: dial tcp: lookup production.cloudflare.docker.com on 10.0.2.3:53: read udp 10.0.2.15:33473->10.0.2.3:53: i/o timeout